# How to read multiple value from a temp table and assign it to a variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following variable @MemberID in my select statement WHERE MemberID = @MemberID  that I would like to assign all the result from my @NotIn temp table. Any input?

```
   Create Table #NotIN(
     MemberId int);

   insert Into #NotIN
     select MemberId
     from Member
     where  CLIENtID = 19800 AND MemberID NOT IN (
     SELECT Distinct MemberID
     FROM [OnDemand].[dbo].[DealerVaultSale]
      where ClientID = 19800
          Union
      SELECT Distinct MemberID
      FROM [OnDemand].[dbo].[DealerVaultService]
      where ClientID = 19800 )

    Select * from #NotIN;

  SELECT [CustomerNumber]
      ,[ClientID]
      ,[MemberID]
      ,[LastImportDateTime]
       FROM [DealerVaultCustomerMemberMap] WHERE MemberID = @MemberID
```

Can I do this

```
 declare @MemberID int
 set @MemberID = (Select * from #NotIN)
```

Comment: You don't need a variable at all. Instead of using `=`, you should use `in`. `where MemberID IN (Select MemberId from #NotIN)`

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by joining your SQL with main table.

```
SELECT [CustomerNumber]
      ,[ClientID]
      ,[MemberID]
      ,[LastImportDateTime]
       FROM [DealerVaultCustomerMemberMap] a JOIN 
(select MemberId
     from Member
     where  CLIENtID = 19800 AND MemberID NOT IN (
     SELECT Distinct MemberID
     FROM [OnDemand].[dbo].[DealerVaultSale]
      where ClientID = 19800
          Union
      SELECT Distinct MemberID
      FROM [OnDemand].[dbo].[DealerVaultService]
      where ClientID = 19800 )) b ON  a.member_id = b.member_id;
```